# what is wrong with the query ? or code?

Tags: c#, arrays

A user enter in the search charactre like this**"blue,yellow green,red pink,stack over flow"**
Now i want to put this into array, and search it using the following code,

```
string[] search = mysearch.Split(',');
List<Result> myresult = new List<Result>();

for (int kk = 1; kk < search.Length; kk++)
  {  


where += " And '%" + search[kk] + "%'";              
    OleDbCommand sqlcmdCommand0 = new OleDbCommand("select Distinct name from table1  where       search like '%" + search[0] + "%' " + where + " order by name", myCon);
     sqlcmdCommand0.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      OleDbDataReader sda = sqlcmdCommand0.ExecuteReader();

 while(sda.read())
    {
         myresult.name= sda.getString(0);
         Result.add(myresult);
    }
}
return Result;
```

The query Look like this :

```
select Distinct name from table1 where search like '%blue%' And '%yellow%' And '%Green %' order by name
```

and it is supposed to look like this:

```
select Distinct name from table1 where search like '%blue%' And '%yellow Green %' order by name
```

but the problem is that it seperate the string after the space not at the comma, and i want to put the string into the array after the occurances of comma not after the space between the character.

Comment: Never knew "stack over flow" was a color.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What should the result look like?

Comment: your example should do the separation on the comma, can you please post some real code to see if there's not something else going one ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... this code correctly splits the string at commas, not spaces.

Comment: @Krtek I use this in the query and the query look like this :  `select Distinct name from table1 where search like '%blue%'  And '%yellow%' And '%Green %' order by name`

Comment: @BoltClock that was something i just put it ;)

Comment: the code is completly correct for the purpose you want, did you even try it in your IDE?

Comment: So your question relies on the outcome of a sql statement? Just iterate through the results of the sql-server!

Comment: @Wegginho i have updated the question now you can see it and tell me.

Comment: What shall I tell you? you have updated the description but not your question dude.

Comment: Even after your edit, there is a step missing - how are you getting the array into the sql statement?

Comment: `string[] search = mysearch.Split(',');` is doing what you want. Your mistake is elsewhere.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I will post the code as well

Comment: @safi, please post the code used to generate the SQL query

Comment: @Thomas Levesque I have posted the code which is used to generate the query

Comment: I don't think this is your actual code, it won't even compile... You're using `kk` before it's declared, and you don't use it in the loop

Comment: Come on mate. That is NOT the code you are using. I think you might need to start a new question, with the actual problem, not the one you've posted here, because it's clear that there is no problem with the split function, or how you've used it.

Comment: @Dave Arkell Can you see the question fully with the code as well, i have posted the code and the actual problem as well

Comment: @Thomas Levesque i forgot to put the kk after for loop

Comment: I can see other issues with your code, like the fact that your query will be executed every time you add a new string to the where clause, but the actual where clause appears how you want it. However, for the where clause to work, you need some more work. Look at Guffa's answer.

Comment: @Dve Arkell, yes i want to exectue every time this code to filter the result if a user enter suppose first blue so where will be  blue in search, then if he enter red then the where clause  will be Blue And red.

Comment: This is __Not The Real Code__. Voting to close.

Comment: completely changing the question after people have already answered? come on dude...

Comment: @Henk Holterman @Dormisher Dave Arkell @Thomas Levesque @CodeInChaos ALL why i got a down vote ? i have explained all the things which i have wrote down, So how can i know that i get a down vote?

Comment: @dormisher i have updated the question you can see it there [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790123/problem-with-multiple-search-keywords/5790255#5790255]

Comment: @Dve Arkell i have updated the question you can see it there [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790123/problem-with-multiple-search-keywords/5790255#5790255]

Comment: @Thomas Levesque i have updated the question you can see it there [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790123/problem-with-multiple-search-keywords/5790255#5790255]

Comment: @CodeInChaos i have updated the question you can see it there [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790123/problem-with-multiple-search-keywords/5790255#5790255]

Comment: The reason I downvoted is that I've spent about 30 minutes trying to answer your question, and still I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: @Dave Arkell [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790123/problem-with-multiple-search-keywords] this is the updated question.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think you might just want to throw away your current code... Here's what you need to do to generate the `WHERE` condition:

```
string[] searchTerms = mySearch.Split(',');
StringBuilder conditions = new StringBuilder();
foreach(string term in searchTerms)
{
    if (conditions.Length > 0)
        conditions.Append(" AND ");
    conditions.AppendFormat("search LIKE '%{0}%'", term.Replace("'", "''"));
}
string query = "select Distinct name from table1";
if (conditions.Length > 0)
    query = query + " WHERE " + conditions;
```

Comment: thanks then i have to put the query into the oledbcommand ?

Comment: @safi, yes, I left out that part...

Comment: this is the updated question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790123/problem-with-multiple-search-keywords]

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is not correct, you need a `like` operator for each comparison, and two operands for each operator. Also, you probably want to use the `or` operator between the comparisons, otherwise you will only find the records that contains *all* the colors, not *any of* the colors:

```
select Distinct name
from table1
where
  search like '%blue%' or
  search like '%yellow%' or
  search like '%green%'
order by name
```

Comment: @safi: The SQL is still incorrect.

Comment: @ Guffa So how to make it working?

Comment: @safi: You can use `"where search like '%" + String.Join("%' or search like '%", search) + "%'"` to create the condition. Note that you should verify that the strings doesn't contain any harmful characters, otherwise the query is wide open for SQL injection.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: @Guffa I am sorry i was going to vote up but i clicked that by mistake for which i am indeed sorry.

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to split on comma and space use the overload that takes a params argument, and pass a comma char and a whitespace char:

```
"red, blue green".Split(',', ' ');
```

Comment: That's not the Answer to the Question.

Comment: that's because he completely re-wrote the question after I had answered the original one