# problem with multiple search keywords

Tags: c#, ms-access

i have web-application, in the application a user can search by using a single keyword or multiple keyword. i have used every technique but i do not know what is wrong with this code as it do not filter the result and continue adding new result.
the search keywords are seperated by comma, like **summer,38,blue** these are 3 keywords. the code and structure of the table is give below.

```
publi override list<result> retrunsearch(string search)
{
string[] search = pQuery.Split(',');
List <result> myresult = new List<result>();
for (int i = 1; i < search.Length; i++)
                {

  where += " And '%" + search[i] + "%'";
  OleDbCommand sqlcmdCommand0 = new OleDbCommand("select Distinct name from table1 where     search like '%" + search[0] + "%' " + where + " order by name", sqlcon);
                sqlcmdCommand0.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                OleDbDataReader sdaResult0 = sqlcmdCommand0.ExecuteReader();
                while (sdaResult0.Read())
                {
                    result restult1= new result();
                    result1.name   = sdaResult0.String(0);
                    myresult.add(result1);
                }

                sdaResult0.Close();

}
return myresult;
}

public class result{

public result()
{
}

public string name{get;set;}
}

the structure of the table is: 
id      name           keyword;
1       blue  jeans      blue;
2       blue  jeans      38;
3       blue jeans       summer;
4       black jeans      black;
5       black jeans      38;
6       black jeans      summer;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is wrong with the query ? or code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787946/what-is-wrong-with-the-query-or-code)

Comment: You're building a WHERE clause similar to "WHERE search Like %art%".  Does table1 actually have a field which is named "search"?  You showed us it has a field named "keyword".

Comment: @CodeInChaos it is the complete that is why i send you the link.

Comment: @Hansup, if you read the text of the question the only problem is that it do not filter the result. you can see the @jgauffin discussion sections. yes it has but i think i has mistakenly type in the table1 column name as keyword. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Second go at retrieving records using one or more keywords. I've added some nicer variable names and formatting along with some syntax tips to help with readability.

```
public override List<string> Search(string pQuery)
{
    string[] keywords = pQuery.Split(',');
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    if (keywords.Length == 0)
    {
        // Code expects at least one keyword - throw exception or return null ?
    }

    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    query.Append(
        string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table WHERE keyword LIKE '%{0}%'", keywords[0])
    );

    // Add extra keywords
    if (keywords.Length > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < keywords.Length; i++)
        {
            query.Append(string.Format(" OR keyword LIKE '%{0}%'", keywords[i]));
        }
    }

    // Add order by
    query.Append(" ORDER BY name");

    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query.ToString(), sqlcon))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                results.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: thanks i dont get you what error is in my code, i know i wrote it didnt copied it.

Comment: retrunsearch accessor was misspelt (publi not public) and your where clause string doesn't have a type definition (string where ...). Have you got your code working?

Comment: Thanks I agree my mistakes,no not yet, i am now working on @jgauffin solution you can look at the comments over there, may be you have some good ideas to solve it :)

Comment: Thanks,I have applied your solution but i am thinking you have used OR operater instead of AND,which is not filtering the data.and If i use AND instead of OR in your solution then i get empty result. i appreciate your efforts.

Comment: My only guess is that if you are getting records when you use 'OR', but not if you are using 'AND', then you haven't got any records that have all of the keywords you are specifying. Try running the code with just one keyword, and see whether you get any records.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing a new SELECT statement for each item in the keyword list. Instead, try building the where clause and *then* executing the select statement:

```
public override list<result> retrunsearch(string search)
{
  string[] search = pQuery.Split(',');
  List <result> myresult = new List<result>();

  // Build WHERE
  for (int i = 1; i < search.Length; i++)
    where += " And '%" + search[i] + "%'";

  // Now search
  OleDbCommand sqlcmdCommand0 = new OleDbCommand("select Distinct name from table1 where     search like '%" + search[0] + "%' " + where + " order by name", sqlcon);
  sqlcmdCommand0.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  OleDbDataReader sdaResult0 = sqlcmdCommand0.ExecuteReader();
  while (sdaResult0.Read())
  {
    result restult1= new result();
    result1.name   = sdaResult0.String(0);
    result.add(result1);
  }
  sdaResult0.Close();

  return result;
}
```

A couple of quick notes:

- I'm lazy, so I preserved errors in your code such as not declaring the "where" variable.
- You might need to use "OR" instead of "AND" in your WHERE clause, depending on how you want your search to work.
- The approach you are taking is subject to a SQL injection attack.

Comment: thanks but i do not need to use or as i am using multiple keywords and if i use or then the search result will contain irrelevant records.

Comment: can you look into the question now:

Answer (score 1):

You need to refactor your method a bit. Only the query appending should be in the for loop:

```
public override list<result> retrunsearch(string search)
{
    string[] search = pQuery.Split(',');
    List <result> myresult = new List<result>();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select Distinct name from table1 where search like '%" + search[0] + "%', sqlcon);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    for (int i = 1; i < search.Length; i++)
    {
        cmd.CommandText += " AND search like '%" + search[i] + "%'";
    }
    cmd.CommandText += " order by name";

    OleDbDataReader sdaResult0 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (sdaResult0.Read())
    {
        result restult1= new result();
        result1.name   = sdaResult0.String(0);
        myresult.add(result1);
    }

    sdaResult0.Close();
    return myresult;
}
```

Comment: @jgauffin thanks for the solution but it is giving me syntax missing operator. the query from your code look like this :  `select Distinct name from table1 where search like '%gnu%' search like And '%art%' order by name`

Comment: @jgauffin now i do not get any result. no error no warning msg but no result. `CommandText = "select Distinct name from table1 where search like '%gnu%' And search like '%art%' order by name"` although these records exist in the database.

Comment: Where to you get no result? Are you using a correct `sqlcon` in your application?

Comment: @jgauffin i do not get result as i run the code in break points, so the code execute upto the while and then stops. gives no error and no result it returned.

Comment: @jgauffin i have tried the same query in access  which i have mentioned in the comment no 3. and it do not work, but if i try it in access like this then it work. and it work also in the project but the problem is than it do not filter the result and return the result which contains either first keyword,2nd or both.  `select Distinct name from table1 where search like '%gnu%' And '%art%' order by name`

Comment: You need to change the where clause to use or's instead of and's because you checking a name is all of the clause conditions. e.g. change `cmd.CommandText += " AND search like '%" + search[i] + "%'";` to `cmd.CommandText += " OR search like '%" + search[i] + "%'";`

Comment: @Mike, If i change this to OR then the multiple search keywords will be not specific and will contains all records if they contains only first or any of the keywords in the search bar. so the result be a long list of irrelevant records

Comment: Sorry, yes - I have misread part of your problem. I will update my answer to give a more clear code sample.